# Error while a Flask project turning into a package

Tags: python, flask

i am a noob in python programming. Recently i was learning Flask framework for web development. After completed some basic flask doc demo i was trying to separate my 1 page simple hello world into mvc.
As in the way this is my project structure

```
Main folder
---> application                   [folder]
    --> __init__.py
    --> route.py
--->run.py
```

**At run.py i have this code :**

```
import application
```

**At the application's _*init*_.py i have this code :**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import route
```

**And at route.py i have this code :**

```
from flask import Flask
from application import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello world"

app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Now when a go to my terminal and start server this happens

```
(venv)nihan@rko:~/apps/blog$ python run.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
^C^C127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2013 00:25:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2013 00:25:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Now you can see this script runs correctly but it does not response to and request until i shut the process.

My question is why server does not sends anything until i press **CTRL + C** ? And how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also avoid circular imports, for example by using blueprints.

run.py

```
from application import app
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

application/__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from route import mod

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(mod, url_prefix='/')
```

application/route.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

mod = Blueprint('app', __name__)

@mod.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix of that is
**In route.py** :

```
    from flask import Flask
from application import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello world"

app.run(
    host='0.0.0.0',
    debug=True
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `app.run()` call to `run.py`. This should happen after everything related to the app is imported, it's not a good idea to have it inside the app itself.